# What does android:pathAdvancedPattern mean?

Tags: android

In the  element of intent-filter, I noticed there is the "android:pathAdvancedPattern" attribute. What "advanced" pattern does it support? I cannot find any doc saying its usage, even the Android official doc.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood based on the document in [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path) it supports regex